# Is it true that an expedited review in the app store is not allowed for more than one application?

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect

I have developed an iPhone application and submitted this to the iTunes Connect successfully. My app status has got change to "Waiting For Review". I would to know that if i have already requested for expedited review of my previous application before one month, is it possible to request again for expedited review in the app store for my current application? I have heard to peoples that we can only request for expedited review once in a year.

Comment: Why don't you just give it a try?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's an automated system, I once requested two expedited reviews in a row (due to my own improper testing), and got both accepted.

So no, no firm rule, but they'll probably look at your history when deciding, and your reason for asking for an expedited review.

Answer (score 0):

there are no limits to how many app reviews you can ask to be expedited.

Comment: And you know this how?

Answer (score 0):

You can expedite your reviews number of times , but remember that you should have strong reason for it like time sensitive event of app or critical bug fixing