# iOS app consecutive Expedite review Request

Tags: app-store-connect

I just made an "Expedite review" request to apple for a major bug yesterday and Apple approved the app in few hours.

Now (Today) I want to request Expedite review again of-course for a major reason.

What is the chance of approval again?

Will that affect my future requests?

Answer (score 1):

I was tempted to vote to close this as dupe rather than opinion based but let’s set aside any presumption that we on the outside could know how many people run the exception queue and if it’s commonly abused by less than critical requests or they really don’t mind honest exceptions if [they can manage the requests](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151676/) easily.

You can always request an exception based on the situation you face today, but clearly the people that run the review queue will eventually decline requests if a “boy who cries wolf” situation happens.

- [Can I request Apple to expedite the approval of a new version of my app to rectify a critical bug](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/289008/)

If you continually fail to QA your apps, that’s a strong signal to reviewers to deny your changes. I would take your lumps and submit normal priority. The reviewers might see your second request and know it’s going to be easy to approve. Unless you are truly fixing something that puts the customer at risk, this next expedited request should really be for a big show stopper if you “ring the emergency help” bell again so soon. I’m sure if your issues are clearly seen as anomalies and actually critical, you’ll face no permanent sanction for using the expedite for two actual cases where it was called for in Apple’s eyes.